# Как нарисовать такое при помощи svg в html?

Tags: css3, html5, svg

Здравствуйте как нарисовать такую фигуру в svg 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

Очень простой редактор svg [CССЫЛКА](https://photolessons.org/svg/)

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path id="svg_2" d="m3,108c0,0 0,35 0,35c0,0 89,-20 149,-15c60,5 196,36 310,37c114,1 176,-21 176,-21c0,0 -1,-36 -1,-36c0,0 -634,0 -634,0z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```